# What is the best way to check if a nested property exists in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm making an API call that 99% of the time has this value defined: awayTeam.record[0].displayValue

The one percent of the time, however, record is not defined or some other nested object is not defined. Is there a clean one line solution to check wether record exists?

I have tried things like this:

```
<h1> {awayTeam.record[0]?.displayValue || "0-0"} </h1>
```

and

```
<h1> {awayTeam.record[0].displayValue ?? "0-0"} </h1>
```

I have quite a lot of properties like this, so I would like to find a clean solution for this issue. Thanks!

Comment: What is "unclean" about your solutions above? (Note: If `record`, itself, may be `undefined` [or `null`] you need to also make the `[0]` optional: `awayTeam.record?.[0]?.displayValue ?? "0-0"`.)

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware that you could check if record was undefined before accessing it.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution seems fine and "clean".

If you want to prevent the usage of the optional chaining ('?'),
You can declare a function that returns a boolean indicating whether a property exists

```js
/**
 * Checks if a nested property exists within an object.
 * 
 * @param {Object} obj - The object to check.
 * @param {...string|number} args - Path to the nested property (as a series of arguments).
 * @returns {boolean} Returns true if the property exists, false otherwise.
 */
const checkNestedProperty = (obj, ...args) => {
    return args.reduce((current, key) => (current && current[key] !== undefined) ? current[key] : undefined, obj) !== undefined;
}
```

Using it as the following:

```
function TeamComponent({ awayTeam }) {
    const hasDisplayValue = checkNestedProperty(awayTeam, 'record', 0, 'displayValue');

    return (
        <div>
            {hasDisplayValue ? (
                <p>Record: {awayTeam.record[0].displayValue}</p>
            ) : (
                <p>Record not available</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a small function like

```
function safe(fn, alt) {
    try {
        return fn()
    } catch (e) {
        return alt
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
<h1>{safe(_ => awayTeam.record[0].displayValue, "0-0")}</h1>
```

This way you don't have to think where to put these question marks.

Answer (score 1):

@T.J. Crowder made a comment suggesting [optional array chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
awayTeam.record?.[0]?.displayValue
```

This is great, but not strictly type-safe in TypeScript because the nullability on array access is swallowed. There is a new array [method `at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) which addressed this by returning `T | undefined`:

```
const array = [1,2,3]

const unchecked = array?.[0] // number
const checked = array.at(0) // number | undefined
```

You can use

```
awayTeam.record.at(0)?.displayValue
```

Answer (score 0):

**The one percent of the time, however, record is not defined or some other nested object is not defined.**

**Read Below Code:**

```js
const arr = [{displayValue:"Test 1"},{displayValue:"Test 2"},{displayValue:""},{displayValue:null}];

const awayTeam = {record:arr};

console.log(awayTeam?.record);
console.log(awayTeam?.record?.[0]?.displayValue || "0-0");
console.log(awayTeam?.record?.[1]?.displayValue || "0-0");
console.log(awayTeam?.record?.[2]?.displayValue || "0-0");
console.log(awayTeam?.record?.[3]?.displayValue || "0-0");

/* || (Logical OR)  returns the right hand value if the left hand value evaluates to false and includes undefined and null but also 0 and ''.*/

/* ?? (Nullish Coalescing Operator) returns the right hand value only if the left hand value is either null or undefined.*/
```